# Coinbase web API through Node fetch "invalid API key" (not Coinbase pro)

Tags: node.js, api, cryptography, coinbase-api

Just trying to get my Coinbase balance. I have tried making a bunch of different API keys, keep getting the same error:

> {
> "errors": [{
> "id": "authentication_error",
> "message": "invalid api key"
> }]
> }

Im using Node.js through Netlify Lambda functions.

Here's my code:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch"
import crypto from "crypto"
const mykey = '<KEY>'
const mysecret = '<SECRET>'


exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const url = `https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts`
    var nonce = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() * 1e-3)
    var my_hmac = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', nonce+'POST'+'v2/accounts', mysecret)
    my_hmac.update(nonce + url)
    var signature = my_hmac.digest('hex')
    var msg;
    
    return fetch(url, { headers: 
        {
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY' : mykey,
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature, 
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': nonce,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        // console.log(res)
        res.json
    })
    .then(data => {

        return ({
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
    })
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong names for the tokens.

- `ACCESS_KEY` is supposed to be `CB-ACCESS-KEY`
- `ACCESS_SIGNATURE` is supposed to be `CB-ACCESS-SIGN`
  I couldn't find info about the nonce. I found this over [here](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?javascript#api-key).

Update:
`signature` looks like it is not made properly:

- The `nonce+'POST'+'/v2/accounts'` is supposed to be the value in `my_hmac.update`
- In turn for the `createHmac` it is only supposed to be `SHA256` and `mysecret`
- The signature pre-hash value is supposed to have a `/` at the beginning
- A useful reference is
  [here (be sure to click node.js at the top)](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication).

Comment: Sorry, yeah. the attributes without CB are from v1 of the API. I had it running with CB and still saying wrong API key